# Usage of the phrase "in itself" in this specific context?

Tags: word-formation, format

> "The watching in itself of this video put my brain in a bit of a
>   knot."

If I want to use the term "in itself", is this the correct way to format a sentence, if I want to put emphasis on the "watching" -part?

Other examples also welcome, which do not include "in itself".

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not an expert, just visiting, but I don't think it's correct in this context.  Using "in itself" here implies that the *act* of watching the video is what prompted the result.  In this instance, unless you were watching the video through a complex series of mirrors or something, I don't see how the watching of the video could have put your brain in a knot.

edit: if your intent was to indicate that the content of the video itself had no impact on putting your brain in a knot, then I'd say you nailed it.

Comment: Do you have an other suggestion that would emphasize the watching itself, not the content of the video? Thanks for the fast reply.

Comment: If that was actually your intent then you nailed it.

Comment: I was about to comment that 'in itself' should follow "video".  But it's fine if you want to emphasise the activity of watching (either *how* you watched, or the fact that you *watched* rather than, say, *listened*, or *had the video described to you*, or...)

Comment: Would it flow better if you punctuated it like this: `The watching, in itself, of the video put my brain in a bit of a knot.`